# What does map.put return?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, return-type

I tried to get the return type of put method of the map interface. When I print for the first time it is printing null and after updating the key I get the previous value.
So, can anyone tell me what is the return type of the put method in the map interface?

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
System.out.println(map.put(1, "ABC"));
System.out.println(map.put(1, "XYZ"));

Output:
null
ABC
```

Comment: It's the type of the value (`V` in `<K, V>`). See [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-). The first time you get `null` because there was no value already associated with the key in the map.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Your code does not reflect what your saying and does not produce the output you show. You probably meant to print the result of `put`, that also explains the output. But in your current snippet you print `get` which would produce a different result.

Comment: It returns the value previously associated with the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return type of put method in the map is the value type.

Method declaration of put:
**V put(K key, V value);**

Where,

key: key with which the specified value is to be associated

value: value to be associated with the specified key

return type: The previous value associated with the **key**, or **null** if there was no mapping for key. *A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key if the implementation supports null values*.

For Example -

System.out.println(map.put(1, "ABC"));  --> In this case there is no value associated with the key **1**, so it returns **null**

System.out.println(map.put(1, "XYZ"));  --> When you are storing a new value against an already stored key, the new value will replace the previous value and the put method will return the previous value which was overridden. In this case, it will return **ABC**.

Answer (score 4):

As per java docs:

> The put returns the previous value associated with key, or null if
>   there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that
>   the map previously associated null with the key if the implementation
>   supports null values.)

In your case when you did `map.put(1, "ABC")` nothing was associated with `key 1` so it `returns null` but when you use `put(1, "XYZ")` then there was already an `entry exists` against the `key 1` so it returns "ABC"

Comment: He is doing `System.out.println(map.get(1))` This is not expected behaviour??

Comment: Yes, OP's output is the expected behaviour and in my answer, I have just explained why he getting such output.

Comment: Now that the question has been edited to point out the correct question, your answer is correct. Earlier the question never printed what OP claimed!

Comment: After 3 years using map and I just found out about this??? Am I crazy... I swear it always gave you the value recently put. I think I need to change all my implementations of Map since my own maps gives you the most recent input....smh

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-), it's a generic function that returns the same datatype as the map value. So, in your case it should return `String`.

Comment: okay, But why it is returning null one time and "ABC" other time? Can you elaborate on this, please?

Comment: This function returns the old value of the specified key. At first, it didn't exist so there's no old value. On the other hand, when you update the value in the next step, it returns the first value. For example, if you update it again, it's supposed to return `"XYZ"`.

Answer (score 1):

you can read in the doc:  [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-)

```
V put(K key, V value)
```

> **Returns**:
>       the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map
>   previously associated null with key, if the implementation supports
>   null values.)

so, since your map is declared as

```
Map<Integer, String> map
```

the Value **V** is the String type, and therefore calling **put** will return string.

*but what is the value that I get?* may you be asking to yourself....

then take a deep look in the source code...

HashMap's *put* method is actually invoking the final method **putVal**

and is implemented like:

```
final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,boolean evict) {
        Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> p; int n, i;
        if ((tab = table) == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
            n = (tab = resize()).length;
        if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)
            tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
        else {
            Node<K,V> e; K k;
            if (p.hash == hash &&
                ((k = p.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                e = p;
            else if (p instanceof TreeNode)
                e = ((TreeNode<K,V>)p).putTreeVal(this, tab, hash, key, value);
            else {
                for (int binCount = 0; ; ++binCount) {
                    if ((e = p.next) == null) {
                        p.next = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
                        if (binCount >= TREEIFY_THRESHOLD - 1) // -1 for 1st
                            treeifyBin(tab, hash);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (e.hash == hash &&
                        ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                        break;
                    p = e;
                }
            }
            if (e != null) { // existing mapping for key
                V oldValue = e.value;
                if (!onlyIfAbsent || oldValue == null)
                    e.value = value;
                afterNodeAccess(e);
                return oldValue;
            }
        }
        ++modCount;
        if (++size > threshold)
            resize();
        afterNodeInsertion(evict);
        return null;
    }
```

and in the logic, **the method returns the previous value found in the map for the given key...**

that means the first time you do

`put(1,"abc");` 
it returns null, because there was nothing in the map.
if you do again 
`put(1,"xyz");` then the method is returning "***abc***", because is the last value found in the map for the key = 1

Comment: I disagree with the `instanceof` operator, if everything was declared in a type safe manner, with no rawtypes and no unchecked casts. Then the return type **must be** `String` or `null`, so a `null`-check is enough. (Also `instanceof` does an implicit `null`-check`, so your last code snippet wouldn't work

Comment: _if you need to know what type is that null_ - `null` has no type, `obj instanceof String` is never true if `obj == null`

Answer (score 0):

This method returns returns previous value associated with the key if present, else return null. So return type in above case is String.