# How to extract text from element, element found but text is empty?

Tags: java, android, selenium, ui-automation

I am working on mobile automation testing on an Android device and I am trying to extract a specific text from an element using Xpath and Selenium. I have tried Javascript, adding a sleep before the line etc, but without success. The code finds the element but it does not return the value "5+5" as expected but it returns empty value as it finds no value. What can the problem be and how can I extract the value that I need?

Here is some code:

```
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<>();
JavascriptExecutor js = driver;
WebElement myelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(AppConstant.ANDROID_COMBINAZIONE_VALUE));
            
String text = scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) myelement).getText());
//String value = seetest.hybridRunJavascript(AppConstant.ANDROID_COMBINAZIONE_VALUE, 0, "return arguments[0].text");
System.out.println(text + ":**********************************************");
Assert.assertEquals(text.replaceAll("\\s", ""), comb.replaceAll("\\s", ""));
```

Comment: Need to see `ANDROID_COMBINAZIONE_VALUE` how it looks like in UI and DOM structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that it is returning the blank value?

**As per my understanding, your code seems incorrect and a null return indicate that the map previously associated null with key.**

```
String text = scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) myelement).getText());
```

***Note: This will always yield you a Null result.***

please check the below link to understand it in depth:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63118437/5372079

**Patch:**

```
scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) myelement).getText());
String text = scrollObject.get("element");
```

**Complete Code:**

```
    HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<>();
    JavascriptExecutor js = driver;
    WebElement myelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(AppConstant.ANDROID_COMBINAZIONE_VALUE));
    scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) myelement).getText());
    String text = scrollObject.get("element");
    //String value = seetest.hybridRunJavascript(AppConstant.ANDROID_COMBINAZIONE_VALUE, 0, "return arguments[0].text");
    System.out.println(text + ":**********************************************");
    Assert.assertEquals(text.replaceAll("\\s", ""), comb.replaceAll("\\s", ""));
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the link. After reading it I understood how to solve the problem.